# How to use a javascript variable in the OnClientClick attribute of a ASP.NET control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a single textbox `txtUser` where a user can input a username, and there is a Delete button beside this textbox. I am providing a delete confirmation using the `OnClientClick` attribute of the `<asp:button>`.

The message is: *Are you sure you want to delete this user?* This works.

I want to change this message to *Are you sure you want to delete 'username'?* by getting the value of the username from the textbox using the `GetElementByID("<%= txtUser.ClientID %>")` and storing it in a variable `user`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var username = document.GetElementByID(<%= txtUser.ClientID %>")
</script>
```

Now I want to use this `username` variable in the OnClientClick call. I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
    <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete "+username+"');">
Delete</asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var username = document.getElementByID("<%= txtUser.ClientID %>").value;
</script>
```

then

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete '+username+'?');">Delete</asp:Button>
```

Should do it. You need to get the value of the text box, and then append the username to the are you sure string, not append it to the ASP control.

As a word of possible warning, if attempt to get the value of the textbox and assign it to `username` before the textbox is rendered, it will result in an error. Make sure the assignment of `username` is after the textbox in the markup, or use something like `window.onload`.

Comment: I made sure the script tag is after textbox in the markup, but I am  seeing the alert message as _are you sure you want to delete undefined_?

Comment: I'd make sure `txtUser.ClientID` is returning the same ID as the `<input type="text" ...` has in the source code

Comment: I was getting `object doesn't support GetElementById` all along when I checked in IE JS Debugger. It turned out to be as simple as writing `GetElementById` instead of `getElementById`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit clearer for the next developer who wants to look at what you did

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUserName()
{
 var userTextBoxId ='<%= txtUser.ClientID %>'; 
 return document.getElementByID(userTextBoxId).value;
}
</script>
```

Then

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete ' + getUserName() + '?');">Delete</asp:Button>
```